# Migration of SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, migration

We have a situation here our application is working on `SQL server` on a cluster environment. Now we wish to migrate the database to a standalone environment, we have approx 2850 databases `1.6 TB` in size.

The DBA has said it is not possible to migrate that many database as they need to Export/Import one database at a time. So 2850 databases will take hell lot of time.

Do you think is this the only way to perform migration in `SQL server` or there is more innovative way of performing this operation.

Comment: Why are you moving away from Cluster to standalone you would loose HA. Ignore the DBA.

Comment: Its a recommendation from the company as their application will not give good performance on cluster environment

Comment: That is a big migration but tools like DBAtools can really help. https://dbatools.io

Comment: dbatools is licensed tool?

Comment: I do not agree that moving to standalone will give you performance boost. Please check before migrating, moving away from cluster will take away fault tolerance

Comment: I agree with James, 2850 databases for a total size of 1.6TB should really take no time at all with Dbatools.  Also, if there is an application performance problem and not a sql problem then the problem is with the application code. Not the server.  Also agree with Shanky, ignore the DBA or inform them of dbatools. I have had a lot of success with apps using cluster such as Dynamics, Great Plains.

Comment: Why migrate at all? Just break the cluster and you are done, you have a standalone server. And you don't need to export/import databases, you can backup/restore to a new system. Heck, you could also shut down the instance and copy the storage, start up a new server and point to the data files. Lots of options to get this done quickly.